# Is there a truly user friendly guide on how to handle iOS Certificates and Provisioning Profiles? – Xcode 7.3 / iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, certificate, code-signing

I'm getting a warning that `The provisioning profile "iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: *" is expiring soon`. I'm not sure what to do and the Apple documentation, even the Quick Start Guide, is overwhelming and confusing for me.

Some developers say "Just wait until it expires, Xcode will then offer to fix it.", others like Jared Sinclair [adamantly oppose doing that](http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/116436789850/follow-these-guidelines-and-never-struggle-with). I'd do what he suggests, but I'm not sure how and would likely mess up stuff.

Is there a truly user friendly guide on how to handle iOS Certificates and Provisioning Profiles?

Comment: Exactly this. You are most certainly not alone. They tell you what to do but any starting point seems arbitrary. +1.

Comment: I think you need to divide and conquer. Your question does contain an issue that could stand on its own as a question, but instead this question is mostly about your discontentment and not really a question anybody can answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what specific step you're stumped on - since an error signing development builds will cascade and cause issues when you upload. Uploading can have new issues if you don't have problems running development builds.

The outline I use is:

- https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing/

It breaks down the steps to code signing which also deals with profiles. I'll assume you are set up with a proper app / bundle ID in iTunes connect. If that needs guidance, you can refer to this diagram from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

[image]

The green boxes are the iTunes Connect portions you need to accomplish in the web app or iTunes Connect iOS app.

If the full process is too much, just focus on breaking up the process into smaller chunks or try reviewing the [quick start guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013839).

Worst case, if you don't have the time to work through things - you could see about partnering with another developer or paying someone to help you set things up. If you want to focus on the coding - outsourcing the management to someone that's already done the learning and has a handful of apps through all the steps can probably save you time struggling with things that don't in the end make a better app but help you navigate the systems for submitting apps.

Comment: Thank you for the effort you put into this, really appreciate it. Unfortunately, I've come to the conclusion that the Apple documentation is basically unusable. For example, the App Distribution Workflow is one of the worst. Right away it starts out with "To learn how to", then lists a truckload of stuff, some with duplicate "resolutions." This is exactly how not to write documentation. The more options one has, the less likely one will be confident that the choice is the optimum one. The Quick Start Guide starts off promising, but then in one or two "Next" clicks falls into the same pattern.

Comment: Also - don't forget that tech is really about [overcoming the struggles](http://twitter.com/kronda/status/717068807093624832) _everyone_ has with code, change and documentation or lack thereof. You're not wrong about it being hard @YiminRong